# Use ConfuserEX To Automatically Obfuscate A Built Output

Tags: c#, obfuscation

So here is what I am attempting to do:

I have an application that is going to build a file by clicking a button I have the code for the file it is building in a resource. I need to be able to obfuscate that output in the process of it building the file.

I have taken a look at the following resources yet they are only obfuscating the actual build itself and it will not obfuscate the output that the builder will build. 
Resources I Have Already Looked At But Have Not Helped: (I am including them for reference)
http://wittylog.com/how-to-perform-automatic-obfuscation-using-visual-studio-201315

Comment: Do you want to obfuscate *one, single file from the resources*, that contains code, and *exclude everything else*? Or, do you want automatically obfuscate *all executables* during the build? What button do you click, do you mean "Build Solution"? I am not sure from your question.

Comment: In the application that I have developed I have a button called "Protect" (https://imgur.com/a/zfTlQ) upon clicking "Protect" it is going to build an executable to a selected directory. In the process of it building that executable and saving it I need it to obfuscate.

Comment: Now it's clear, and what's the problem with ConfuserEx? ConfuserEx uses simple XML project file, which points to *.exe or *.dll files, that should to be obfuscated. So, you just need create/generate/point to project file and non-obfuscated file to start. You can temporary save those files into %TEMP% directory; start ConfuserEx by pressing button in your program, grab obfuscated result and delete temporary files from %TEMP% directory.